# Google Fonts subset issue

Tags: google-fonts

I have an issue with a few character that are not working with google fonts.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/p3ervgp4/

Like the "Ą" is not working. I already added the `&subset=latin,latin-ext` params but thats not fixing the issue.

Only if I add the character as `&text=Ą` it works. So I could prove that the font is supporting these characters. But thats not an option for me to add all possible characters to the text param.

Any idea how I can fix these characters?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: I haven't found a better solution as the text parameter I mentioned in my question. Means I add all possible character in the text string and not the currect text. this way it has not to load the font every time again when the text is changing.